# Error ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MSSQL with PHP try catch

Tags: php, try-catch, sql-server-2014

```
<?php
  try {   
     $db->query("BEGIN TRANSACTION");

         $db->db_insert('INSERT',$FIELDS);

     $db->query("COMMIT TRANSACTION");
  } catch(Exception $e){
     $db->query("ROLLBACK TRANSACTION");
  }
?>
```

My code Commit ok. But When Rollback it error " The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION. "

Comment: So, does your db server support transcation?

Comment: Yes. I use SQL SERVER 2014 or I can check ?

Comment: if you use PDO just try `$pdo->beginTransaction();  `  `$pdo->rollback()`   `$pdo->commit()` function

Comment: I no use PDO. Ok I see this ploblem. Thank you for help.